# Embedded Google map not working

Tags: google-maps

I have found similar posts suggesting I need to add output=embed to the end of the iframe URL but I still get an error (am outputting html from jade hence the syntax).

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.uk/maps/preview?f=q' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.


iframe(width="250", height="250", frameborder="0", scrolling="no", marginheight="0", marginwidth="0", src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=London&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=lo&amp;sll=51.528642,-0.101599&amp;sspn=0.815911,1.716614&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=London,+United+Kingdom&amp;ll=51.511307,-0.11982&amp;spn=0.053418,0.085831&amp;z=12&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"
```

I am working from localhost. Could this be an issue? From what I've read it is because Google redirects to the new maps.

UPDATE: I have tried on a regular static page and it works. So it must be to do with me using localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the URL is encoded - `& to &amp;`.

Look at the fix [here](https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=London&aq=0&oq=lo&sll=51.528642,-0.101599&sspn=0.815911,1.716614&t=m&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=London,+United+Kingdom&ll=51.511307,-0.11982&spn=0.053418,0.085831&z=12&iwloc=A&output=embed)

```
https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=London&aq=0&oq=lo&sll=51.528642,-0.101599&sspn=0.815911,1.716614&t=m&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=London,+United+Kingdom&ll=51.511307,-0.11982&spn=0.053418,0.085831&z=12&iwloc=A&output=embed
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually didn't try this because it was too obvious, ha. Unescaping wasn't necessary in my test.html page. Maybe it's a Jade thing?